# What does a Valve Anti-Cheat (VAC) notification look like?

Tags: steam

I'd like to know what messages appear when somebody is cheating and VAC detects it. Do they appear in-game (for games which support VAC natively) or via Steam's game overlay (opened by pressing shift-tab)? Does the game immediately close to show the message? What happens on the screen of the banned player and the players on the same server throughout the whole process?

I couldn't find unmodified screenshots or detailed enough info on google. [This post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3639/how-does-valve-anti-cheat-vac-work) briefly lists the things that trigger a ban, but not how it notifies the user of detected cheating visually.

Comment: There is one answer already, but don't be discouraged to post other screenshots and descriptions of what happens in other games.

Comment: A partial answer can be found in this question: [What is “OpenGL” and why did a player get banned for it?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/266282/72346)

Comment: @OrangeDog something tells me that was a custom server's anti-cheat protection. Valve would probably have included a better text description than that. But what do I know. Anyway, without screenshots as proof it's not of much interest to me.

Answer (score 14):

**Caveat:** I have never been VAC banned so all information provided below is from different sources across the internet.

---

### When a player on the server is VAC banned

The notification most likely varies slightly from game to game. In Source games, a message will appear in the chat stating something like

> Player [PlayerName] has left the game: [VAC Banned from secure server]

You can see this in this screenshot:
[image: Player has been VAC banned]
<sup>[Source](http://esport.aftonbladet.se/csgo/admin-relieved-faceit-duties-vac-ban-joke/)</sup>

(It's fairly blurry sorry, I'm still looking for a better quality picture)

---

### When you are banned

Again, the notification varies slightly from game to game, but if you are VAC-banned mid game, you will get a notification similar to this:

[image: CS:GO VAC message]

According to the [TF2 Wiki](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Valve_Anti-Cheat), you will recieve the following notification when you try to connect to a VAC-enabled server.

[image: VAC Ban Notification]
<sup>Message displayed to a VAC-banned client.</sup>

The TF2 wiki explains in further detail the different measures that take place in the event of a VAC Ban. In addition to receiving the above message:

> those who are VAC Banned have all non-purchased items deleted from their backpack.

Needless to say, it would not be a very pleasant situation to be in.

#### Sources:

- [TF2 Wiki: Valve Anti-Cheat](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Valve_Anti-Cheat)
- [Counterstrike Wiki: Valve Anti-Cheat](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Valve_Anti-Cheat)

Comment: you also get some text on your profile that says how many times you have been banned and days since the ban

Comment: @CreeperzEdge - indeed. I didn't mention it as it wasn't really what the OP was asking but true nonetheless :-)

Comment: @CreeperzEdge times? I thought it was permanent, and therefore should only happen once? Or can you go to non-vac secure servers and be "banned" repeatedly, but then nothing should happen because you're on an unsecured server… Could someone clarify?

Comment: @user1306322 - Bans aren't across an account, they occur per-game engine. As per the [TF2 Wiki](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Valve_Anti-Cheat): *"Those who are VAC Banned cannot enter a VAC-enabled server. However, this only applies to the engine the game uses. For example, if you are banned on Counter-Strike or Half-Life, only games which use the GoldSource engine will be affected. You can still play games and connect to secure servers on games that do not use the same engine."*

Comment: I thought OP was looking for messages when *someone else* gets VAC-banned, not when you get banned.

Comment: @OrangeDog - A lot more people would regularly see the message when someone else gets banned. The actual "You have been banned" message is not something that 99% of people would never see :-)

Comment: Actually I'm interested in both sides' view of the event. Thanks for bringing this up, I'll update the question.

Comment: @user1306322 - Updated to match. I'm trying to find a clearer picture but not having any luck at the moment :-(

Comment: "some text on your profile"? Which profile and where is the text?

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard - Sorry for late reply. It's on the right-hand side of someone's main profile screen. [Example](http://i62.tinypic.com/11rq06h.png)